# ERROR HbaseConnector: Can't get the location for replica 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, hbase

I'm trying to perform some read/write operation with Hbase using Spark. When I'm running my spark code using spark-submit command

```
bin/spark-submit --master local[*] --class com.test.driver.Driver  /home/deb/computation/target/computation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "function=avg" "signals=('.tagname_qwewf')" "startTime=2018-10-10T13:51:47.135Z" "endTime=2018-10-10T14:36:11.073Z"
```

it's executing without any error.
But when I'm trying to do the same from Intellij I'm getting the below errors

```
8/12/17 01:51:45 ERROR HbaseConnector: An exception while reading dataframe from HBase
18/12/17 01:51:45 ERROR HbaseConnector: Can't get the location for replica 0
18/12/17 01:51:45 ERROR Driver: No historical data found for signals in the expression.
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this issue.